# TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to [[127.0.0.1]:10050]: cannot connect with TLS and certificate: no valid certificate loaded

Tags: zabbix

This is Zabbix certificate load issue: "Get value from agent failed: TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to [[127.0.0.1]:10050]: cannot connect with TLS and certificate: no valid certificate loaded"

TLS handshake works fine directly from host machine (CLI) but nothing works from Zabbix UI. I created a host and added an item with HTTP agent (gave URL and put the certs in the path
/usr/share/zabbix/ssl/certs = zabbix.pem file
/usr/share/zabbix/ssl/keys = zabbix.key file

Anyone experienced the same problem can help in this? I'm using Zabbix 4.4.4 version.

Below are the logs from Wireshark:

4   0.028862    a.b.c.d x.x.x.x TLSv1.2 319 Client Hello

5   0.058573    x.x.x.x a.b.c.d TCP 68  9443 → 53132 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=252 Win=28160 Len=0 TSval=2097779469 TSecr=189774380

6   0.063987    x.x.x.x a.b.c.d TLSv1.2 1346    Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done

7   0.064002    a.b.c.d x.x.x.x TCP 68  53132 → 9443 [ACK] Seq=252 Ack=1279 Win=32128 Len=0 TSval=189774415 TSecr=2097779476

8   0.065270    a.b.c.d x.x.x.x TLSv1.2 168 Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

9   0.094524    x.x.x.x a.b.c.d TLSv1.2 75  Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)

Answer (score 0):

Disable PSK encryption on default server 127.0.0.1 within zabbix frontend and ensure all psk settings are commented out

```
sudo nano /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

...
TLSConnect=psk
...
...
TLSAccept=psk
...
...
TLSPSKIdentity=PSK 001
...
TLSPSKFile=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.psk
```

**NOTE: PSK settings are meant ONLY for secondary server monitoring.**
See this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-zabbix-to-securely-monitor-remote-servers-on-ubuntu-20-04) for full directions